# Is the sequence $(f_n)_n $ a convergent sequence in $(L,N) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

We denote by $L$ the real vector space of the functions $g: [0,1] \to\mathbb {R}$ such that $\displaystyle\sup_{\substack{x, y\in [0,1]\\x\neq y}}{\frac {|g (x) - g (y)|}{| x - y | }}$ exists and is finite. We denote
$$
\sup_{\substack{x, y\in [0,1]\\x\neq y}}{\frac {|g (x) - g (y)|}{| x - y | }}=k (g)
$$
The nonnegative-valued function $N:g\to k (g)+\|g\|_{\infty}$ defines a norm on $L$.

Let the sequence of function $f_n\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by
$$f_n(x)\rightarrow \begin{cases}x\,, & x\in[0,\frac {1}{n}]\\ \frac {1}{n}\,, & x\in \mathopen]\frac {1}{n},1]\end{cases}$$

For all $n\geq 1$ we have $N (f_n)=1+\frac {1}{n} $. Is the sequence $(f_n)_n $ a convergent sequence in $(L,N) $?

An idea please.

Comment: I guess that the functions in $L$ are also supposed to be continuous, otherwise $\|g\|_\infty$ might not be well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n$ is convergent there is some function $f$ in your space such that $N(f_n-f)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. Note that $N(f_n-f)=k(f_n-f)+\|f_n-f\|_\infty$ and both $k(\cdot)$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ are nonnegative, so if $f_n$ is convergent then

$k(f_n-f)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ and $\|f_n-f\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. Of course, the converse is also true.

If $f_n$ is convergent, we're specially interested in $\|f_n-f\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, since we know that means $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, so select some $x\in[0,1]$ and let's see what $f(x)$ looks like.

If $x=0$ then for every $n$ we have $f_n(0)=0$, so $f(0)=0$. If $x\in(0,1]$ then there is some $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<x$, so $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n\ge n_0$,

which implies $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, so $f(x)=0$. Therefore, if $f_n$ is convergent, it converges to the zero function (let's call it $f$).

Now, if $f_n$ is convergent, let's see what happens to $N(f_n-f)=N(f_n)$.

As you pointed out $N(f_n)=1+\frac{1}{n}$, so $N(f_n-f)=N(f_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1\neq0$, which is not what should happen. Therefore $f_n$ is not convergent.